# How to add the last row change and user login in the next column

Tags: excel, vba

I have that's code;

1. But i need to have last change date in the same row as the change was made

   A6 = V6 
   B6 = V6 
   A7 = V7 etc.
2. With this last change i need log who edit this by domain login in also row of Column W6,W7 etc.

Can anyone help me with this?

When editing this, I get mistake errors

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xRg As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Range("A6:U1000"))
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Range("V6:V1000").Value = Now()
End Sub
```

When i do something in range A6:U1000 i have timestramp in wrong range 
No A6=V6 but in all Column 1 date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xRg As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Range("A6:U1000"))

If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Range("V" & Target.Row).Value = Now()


End Sub
```

it writes the date in column V int the row that whas changed.

i think thats what u whant.

good luck

Comment: Yes, it's almost done, and i want also to this add name of login domain of user who create change.

Comment: Hi. u can use the cvariable  Environ$("Username"). After the if replace to Range("v" & Target.Row).Value = Now() & " - " & Environ$("Username")